# Adding new search filter

Tags: python, odoo

I am trying to add a date filter to the search engine. For example, the name of the account appears but they are separated over months. There are moviminetos on 03/02/2019 and 03/10/2019 so that they are grouped in the month of March. I tried the following code but it doesn't work, since it tells me that 'Missing view architecture.'.
The code to perform is as follows:

```
    <record id = "customer_multi_search_view" model = "ir.ui.view">
        <field name = "name"> Search </field>
        <field name = "model"> project_rc.account </field>
        <field name = "model_id" ref = "model_proyecto_rc_account" />
        <field name = "arch" type = "xml">
            <search string = "customer search">
                <group expand = "1" string = "Group by">
                    <filter name = "date" string = "Date" domain = "[]" context = "{'group_by': 'title'}" />
                </group>
            </search>
        </field>
    </record>
```

I have to add that the attribute I want to filter is in the "Document_Detail" table, which is the foreign key of the "account" table

Answer (score 0):

to be sure , You can open your odoo session in developer mode and on your module choose search view and like this you can find your foreign key [image]

Comment: I have managed to group by date but it only groups me in the first month where the account is added, for example if the "Bank" account was occupied on 01/01/2019 and on 03/05/2019 in the view it appears to me that it was used only in January and not in May and I want it to come out in January and May.

Comment: have you checked the date of each record

Comment: If I check it and create another account id and that takes it in another month since I put a different movement date but if I now put another movement date in another created month it will remain grouped in the initial month. I attach a link from another publication you make and leave the filter code with a sample link.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59219548/only-grouped-in-a-single-month